# After cloning disk and fixing grub still not being able to boot (BSOD)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I mounted a new NVME disk and cloned my other NVME (smaller) disk into it.
After that grub was not working.
I wiped disk 1 (small)
after using boot-repair now I get BSOD when picking windows on GRUB and GRUB command line when choosing another option listed as windows on BIOS
Now I just have Ubuntu working and Windows is not possible to start.
This is the first report:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4jHYs4hkhy/

after it I run boot-repair again and this is the report:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S2VDNGth8j/

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If Ubuntu is working and Windows is not then that is a Windows problem and outside the scope of Ask Ubuntu. I suggest you try a Windows forum. If you have your Windows installation media there is a boot repair function that may fix it.  Once Windows works from the BIOS you will probably need to update grub to complete the fix

Comment: thanks, but I broke it using boot-repair / grub so perhaps I may fixit that way as well

Comment: Boot-Repair or grub do not break Windows boot. Grub only boots working Windows and Windows updates may turn fast start up back on, preventing grub from Booting Windows. Also reinstall of grub either with Boot-Repair or manually will normally move grub to first in boot order, just as install of Windows boot loader moves it to first in boot order. You show two UEFI Windows boot entries using different ESPs. Do either of those work? Or do you have multiple installs?